# Login ajio.com by Google/Facebook account using selenium web driver in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to selenium  ad I can't able to login ajio 
[coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiNCf.png) using google or my facebook account i even tries windows handling concept but it is having single window id but new tab appears and i tries using some key concepts like(\t) &(t) also but still i cannot pass my mail id in google account tab not only that no others buttons working on that new page pls clear my doubt.. suggest idea to make it work [new tab(which is not allowed to automate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRvBs.png)[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo6qY.png)

Note: I'm using java with selenium 3.141.59 & Chrome version 93.0.4577.82

Comment: please add the new tab screenshot

Comment: added my new tab image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually login window is opening in another tab so you need to switch focus to another window. following code is working for me.

```
Set<String> windowslist = driver.getWindowHandles();
String lastwindow = null;
for(String eachWindow : windowslist){
     lastwindow = eachWindow;
}
driver.switchTo().window(lastwindow);


wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(emailBox));
driver.findElement(emailBox).sendKeys("jayanthbala1993@gmail.com");
```

Comment: whats the error

Comment: but your page is loading withnin 10secs ?

Comment: you need to switch the chrome tab, added above the working code

Comment: what is the error

Comment: it shows couldn't sign you in this app or browser may not secure

Comment: create as separate question, i don't about it